# All processes running on the same core

Tags: multithreading

I found all processes on my machine to only run on a single core and their core affinity set to 0.
Here is a small python script which reproduces this for me:

```py
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np


def do_a_lot_of_compute(a):
    for i in range(1000):
        a = a * np.random.randn(123789)
    return a


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        pool.map(do_a_lot_of_compute, np.arange(10000))
```

htop looks like this:
[image]
And the core affinities are:

```
pid 15977's current affinity list: 0
pid 15978's current affinity list: 0
pid 15979's current affinity list: 0
pid 15980's current affinity list: 0
pid 15981's current affinity list: 0
pid 15982's current affinity list: 0
pid 15983's current affinity list: 0
pid 15984's current affinity list: 0
pid 15985's current affinity list: 0
```

So my question boils down to: Why are the core affinities all set to 0? There are no OMP or KMP environment variables set.

Comment: What happens when you explictly tell your script to use certain cores? E.g. `taskset $mask $script` -- see here : https://baiweiblog.wordpress.com/2017/11/02/how-to-set-processor-affinity-in-linux-using-taskset/ and the `taskset` manual page.

Comment: Manually overwriting the task affinities did not help. It seems that this issue was related to `Slurm` and `PBS` which both enforce the process affinity to a single core if one does not explicitly requests multiple cpu cores.

Comment: If you have the answer please post it so others can benefit .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to `SLURM` and `PBS` setting the core affinity based on the number of requested cores.
In `SLURM` adding the following line enables the use of all cores:

```
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=8
```